# Execute user request in a runkit sandbox session

Tags: php, sandbox, lighttpd, runkit

I have an environment where users upload php projects, something similar to that for a shared hosting.

User's code will have nothing to do with Runkit. Their code has to be executed in my runkit environment.

Is it possible to have a Request handler for lighttpd where I can create an runkit sandbox and execute user's request.